# link_to strips port from site hosted in container

Tags: laravel, nginx, docker

This is a bit of a tricky situation. I'm testing deployment of a Laravel application which I've recently containerised. I've made a container based on [php](http://hub.docker.com/_/php), which runs Apache inside itself to serve the application. If I simply run this container, bound to port 5000, then `link_to('/login')` correctly generates a link pointing to `localhost:5000/login`.

However, now I'm testing an actual deployment scenario, where this container is running behind an nginx load balancer. I've set up a VM using Vagrant, which is running two containers: one for the nginx load balancer, and one for the Apache/Laravel application. I access the VM's port 80 on my host's port 7000.

In this situation, `link_to('/login')` now generates links pointing to `localhost/login`. Where did the port go missing? It should link to `localhost:7000/login`, because that's the port I'm accessing the page on.

How can I debug this? I've tried looking into the implementation of `link_to`, but I suspect the problem is elsewhere.

**EDIT**

I've just discovered that in addition, if I serve the site over HTTPS (terminated at nginx; Apache still does everything over HTTP), this is also stripped from links created by `link_to`. Instead of `https://localhost:7443/login`, the link looks like `localhost/login`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use something like [fideloper/proxy](https://github.com/fideloper/TrustedProxy) to properly handle the proxy headers added by Nginx. I thought I had done this, but I'd forgotten to add the facade to `app/config/app.php`.